# How to center text vertically with a large font-awesome icon?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Lets say I have a bootstrap button with a font-awesome icon and some text:

```
<div>
    <i class='icon icon-2x icon-camera'></i>
    hello world
</div>
```

How do I make text appear vertically centered?
Text is aligned with the bottom edge of the icon now: http://jsfiddle.net/V7DLm/1/

Comment: Add a new class to use on the icon itself:`.fa-center { line-height: inherit!important; vertical-align: middle; }`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

After considering all suggested options, the cleanest solution seems to be setting line-height and vertical-align everything:

See **[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/paulftw/F3KyK/43/)**

**CSS:**

```
div {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 60px;
    padding: 10px;
}
#text, #ico {
    line-height: 50px;
}

#ico {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: What if your container is bigger than 50px? Then it won't work...I have content that changes size and it should have centered icon inside...any idea about that?

Comment: line-height is necessary if line height is not aligning with the parent box height. But this would not be responsive. This answer should help for responsiveness, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124255/center-icon-in-a-div-horizontally-and-vertically

Answer (score 352):

I just had to do this myself, you need to do it the other way around.

- **do not** play with the vertical-align of your text
- play with the vertical align of the font-awesome icon

```html
<div>
  <span class="icon icon-2x icon-camera" style=" vertical-align: middle;"></span>
  <span class="my-text">hello world</span>
</div>
```

Of course you could not use inline styles and target it with your own css class. But this works in a copy paste fashion.

See here:
[Vertical alignment of text and icon in button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478710/vertical-alignment-of-text-and-icon-in-bootstrap-button)

If it were up to me however, I would not use the icon-2x. And simply specify the font-size myself, as in the following

```html
<div class='my-fancy-container'>
    <span class='my-icon icon-file-text'></span>
    <span class='my-text'>Hello World</span>
</div>
```

```css
.my-icon {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.my-text {
    font-family: "Courier-new";
}

.my-fancy-container {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 60px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

for a working example, please see [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3GMjp/77/)

Comment: yes, this is a better solution, thanks. Still seems to require line-height though http://jsfiddle.net/paulftw/F3KyK/41/

Comment: I updated your jsfiddle for how I would do it. I used font-size for the icon instead of using the 2x. http://jsfiddle.net/3GMjp/1/

Comment: In your first piece of code the <span> start tag does not correspond with the ending </i> tag.

Comment: Does not work with some of the icons.  [fa-angle-left example](http://jsfiddle.net/wfx23dkz/)

Comment: important to realize that including the fontawesome js files can also modify the looks. My icon was too far to the top, I deleted the js inclusion to see what would happen and now it's too far to the bottom -.-

Comment: TDDR; *play with the vertical align of the font-awesome icon* fine be me.

Comment: First line really helped me out. I do not really understand why though. +1

Answer (score 60):

I use icons next to text 99% of the time so I made the change globally:

```
.fa-2x {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Add 3x, 4x, etc to the same definition as needed.

Comment: In my opinion this should be the accepted answer, as it is by far the simplest solution, unless I am missing something in the original question. Thanks @rushonerok! I'm not sure why some people say not to use `vertical-align: middle;` - I might be missing something here. Please explain if so.

Comment: @Kendall Roth I think when people say to not use `vertical-align: middle`, they mean *if you are using `block` elements*. If you're using `inline`, `inline-block`, or `table-cell`, you should be good. MDN: [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

Comment: Works like charm! Thank you :D

Comment: I find that on Bootstrap 5 icons, setting the vertical align of the :before element to 'baseline' does the trick:  i.bi:before { vertical-align: baseline; }

Answer (score 29):

if things aren't lining up, a simple `line-height: inherit;` via CSS on specific i.fa elements that are having alignment issues could do the trick simply enough.

You could also feasibly use a global solution, which due to a slightly higher CSS specificity will override FontAwesome's .fa rule which specifies `line-height: 1` without requiring `!important` on the property:

```
i.fa {
  line-height: inherit;
}
```

Just make sure that the above global solution doesn't cause any other issues in places where you might also use FontAwesome icons.

Answer (score 21):

**a flexbox option - font awesome 4.7 and below**

FA 4.x Hosted URL - https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

```css
div {
  display: inline-flex; /* make element size relative to content */
  align-items: center; /* vertical alignment of items */
  line-height: 40px; /* vertically size by height, line-height or padding */
  padding: 0px 10px; /* horizontal with padding-l/r */
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/* unnecessary styling below, ignore */
body {display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;height: 100vh;}div i {margin-right: 10px;}div {background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 87%, 0.5);}div:hover {background-color: hsla(34, 100%, 52%, 0.5);cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
    <i class='fa fa-2x fa-camera'></i>
    hello world
</div>
```

**fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/V7DLm/180/

---

**using flex and font awesome 5**

FA 5.x Hosted URL - https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js

```css
div {
  display: inline-flex; /* make element size relative to content */
  align-items: center; /* vertical alignment of items */
  padding: 3px 10px; /* horizontal vertical position with padding */
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.svg-inline--fa { /* target all FA icons */
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.icon-camera .svg-inline--fa { /* target specific icon */
  font-size: 50px;
}
/* unnecessary styling below, ignore */
body {display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;height: 100vh; flex-direction: column;}div{margin: 10px 0;}div {background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 87%, 0.5);}div:hover {background-color: hsla(212, 100%, 63%, 1);cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
<div class="icon-camera">
    <i class='fas fa-camera'></i>
    hello world
</div>
<div class="icon-clock">
    <i class='fas fa-clock'></i>
    hello world
</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/3bpjvof2/

Comment: This can center an icon vertically within a div, not just within a line of text. Works great!

Answer (score 12):

The simplest way is to set the vertical-align css property to middle

```
i.fa {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: `.svg-inline--fa` for FontAwesome 5

Comment: @darylknight, what does this mean?  How would I activate/use that? Add something after my `fa-clock` in the class?

Answer (score 6):

This worked well for me.

```
i.fa {
  line-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try set your icon as `height: 100%`

You don't need to do anything with the wrapper (say, your button).

This requires Font Awesome 5. Not sure if it works for older FA versions.

```
.wrap svg {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Note that the icon is actually a `svg` graphic.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mriiiron/t512fmso/2/)

Answer (score 3):

For those using Bootstrap 4 is simple:

```
<span class="align-middle"><i class="fas fa-camera"></i></span>
```

Comment: This has no use as vertical-align: middle which is applied by this class is targeting tables only.

Answer (score 2):

Another option to fine-tune the line height of an icon is by using a percentage of the `vertical-align` property. Usually, 0% is a the bottom, and 100% at the top, but one could use negative values or more than a hundred to create interesting effects.

```
.my-element i.fa {
    vertical-align: 100%; // top
    vertical-align: 50%; // middle
    vertical-align: 0%; // bottom
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap the text in a  so you can target it separately. Now if you float both  and  left, you can use line-height to control the vertical spacing of the . Setting it to the same height as the  (30px) will middle align it. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/F3KyK/4/).

New Markup:

```
 <div>
    <i class='icon icon-2x icon-camera'></i>
    <span id="text">hello world</span>
</div>
```

New CSS:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 60px;
    padding: 4px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
i{
    float: left;
}
#text{
    line-height: 30px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Vertical-align doesn't do *anything* on block elements, it only works on inline or table-cell elements.

Comment: I see, setting line-height = container's height and floating things left works and needs less typing. Here's an updated fiddle with noise reduced: http://jsfiddle.net/F3KyK/7/

Comment: It's better to just set `vertical-align: middle` on the icon and text. That way you're not making assumptions about the icon height and there's less CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this question was asked years ago. I think technology has changed quite a bit and browser compatibility is much better. You could use vertical-align but I would consider that some what less scaleable and less reusable. I would recommend a **flexbox** approach.

Here is the same example the original poster used but with flexbox. It styles a single element. If a button size changes for whatever reason, it will continue to be vertically and horizontally centered.

```
.button {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 60px;
    padding: 4px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
```

**Example:** [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iandonahue/cgpe6kqy/)

Answer (score 0):

When using a flexbox, vertical alignment of font awesome icons next to text can be very difficult. I tried margins and padding, but that moved all items. I tried different flex alignments like center, start, baseline, etc, to no avail. The easiest and cleanest way to adjust only the icon was to set it's containing div to `position: relative; top: XX;` This did the job perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply define `vertical-align` property for the icon element:

```
div .icon {
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for me, just making the  element display gird, and aligning content works perfectly. simply solution.

```
.yourfontawesome<i>Element{
display: grid;
align-content: center;
}
```