# Vertical alignment of text and icon in button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alignment, webfonts, font-awesome

I'm having trouble vertically aligning a font-awesome icon with text within a button under the Bootstrap framework. I've tried so many things including setting the line-height, but nothing is working.

```
<button id="edit-listing-form-house_Continue" 
        class="btn btn-large btn-primary"
        style=""
        value=""
        name="Continue"
        type="submit">
    Continue
    <i class="icon-ok" style="font-size:40px;"></i>
</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fPXFY/

How can I get this to work?

Comment: You can simply use flex approach: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 138, accepted):

There is one rule that is set by `font-awesome.css`, which you need to override.

You should set overrides in your CSS files rather than inline, but essentially, the icon-ok class is being set to `vertical-align: baseline;` by default and which I've corrected here:

```
<button id="whatever" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" name="Continue" type="submit">
    <span>Continue</span>
    <i class="icon-ok" style="font-size:30px; vertical-align: middle;"></i>
</button>
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/fPXFY/4/ and the output of which is:

[image]

I've downsized the font-size of the icon above in this instance to `30px`, as it feels too big at `40px` for the size of the button, but this is purely a personal viewpoint. You could increase the padding on the button to compensate if required:

```
<button id="whaever" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" style="padding: 20px;" name="Continue" type="submit">
    <span>Continue</span>
    <i class="icon-ok" style="font-size:30px; vertical-align: middle;"></i>
</button>
```

Producing: http://jsfiddle.net/fPXFY/5/ the output of which is:

[image]

Comment: You may also want to add `margin-top: -0.125em`, as I've found that there is still some space at the top if you use an icon like "bars" (ubiquitous mobile nav button).

Comment: Had a similar problem with Google Material Icons and this fixed it.

Comment: For those that were setting `style="height: x px;"` and still struggling with vertical alignment issues. I found that instead setting  `style="padding: y px;"` did the trick (Bootstrap 4)

Comment: ```vertical-align: middle``` in icon elements did the job, thanks! (In Bootstrap just add the ```align-middle``` class)

Answer (score 23):

Alternativly if your using bootstrap then you can just add `align-middle` to vertical align the element.

```
<button id="whaever" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" style="padding: 20px;" name="Continue" type="submit">Continue
    <i class="icon-ok align-middle" style="font-size:40px;"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! But I use `align-top` because `align-middle` does not make an icon and text on the same level.

Answer (score 14):

Bootstrap 4.3.1 just add class `d-inline-flex align-items-center` in your element parent, you also can use `my-0` to remove excess margin in font-awesome icon, like this:

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-success d-inline-flex align-items-center"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp h1 my-0 pr-2"></i>Whatsapp</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just wrap the button label in an extra span and add `class="align-middle"` to both (the icon and the label). This will center your icon with text vertical.

```
<button id="edit-listing-form-house_Continue" 
    class="btn btn-large btn-primary"
    style=""
    value=""
    name="Continue"
    type="submit">
<span class="align-middle">Continue</span>
<i class="icon-ok align-middle" style="font-size:40px;"></i>
```