# How to vertically align font-awesome icons in a button?

Tags: bootstrap-4, font-awesome, vertical-alignment

My goal is to create a block button with a related icon. Since Bootstrap 4 does not natively support glyphicon anymore and I would prefer using fonts or SVG images over PNG images, I have chosen to use font-awesome v5.

My problem is that the icon is slightly above the text and does not want to center itself, no matter what I tried.

Several answers here on StackOverflow suggested using the `vertical-align` property [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309928/how-to-center-text-vertically-with-a-large-font-awesome-icon)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478710/vertical-alignment-of-text-and-icon-in-bootstrap-button), but this seems to be completely ignored by the icon. I suppose this is due to the fact that both questions were asked in 2013 and font-awesome has been updated since then.

I tried messign with flexboxes, but this ended up moving both the text and the icon. I also tried applying the `align-middle` class to the span, but it didn't work either.

Here is my code so far:

```
<div class="container">
  <p>
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" role="button">
      <span class="fas fa-music fa-lg float-left my-icon"></span> 
      <span class="my-text">Music</span>
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/jgm6L5ad/3/)

As you can see, the icon is still elevated over the text, and I have no idea how to align it vertically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `float-left` on the icon is throwing off the vertical alignment. If you want the icon aligned to the left, and the text centered, you can use flexbox and defined widths like this...

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block d-flex align-items-center px-0" role="button">
      <span class="w-25 fas fa-music fa-lg my-icon"></span> 
      <span class="w-50 my-text">Music</span>
      <span class="w-25"></span>
</a>
```

If you want *both* icon and text centered it's much simpler. Just remove the float and add `align-middle` to the btn...

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block align-middle" role="button">
  <span class="fas fa-music fa-lg my-icon"></span> 
  <span class="my-text">Music</span>
</a>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/iJV8uQDVVD

Answer (score 1):

## Update

- Replaced the Font Awesome 4.7 stylesheet with 5.0.13
- Removed both `<span>`s (all content of `<a>` is now pseudo-elements)
- Removed `<p>` (extra markup isn't needed, `a.btn-block` is already `display:block`)
- Used the pseudo-elements `::after` (text) and `::before` (icon)

---

## [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s8zfew9q/)

### Demo

```css
.icon {
  position: relative;
}

.icon::before {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.5em;
  font-size: 1.2em
}

.icon::after {
  color: #fff;
}


/* Music */

.music::after {
  content: 'Music';
}

.music::before {
  content: '\f001';
}


/* No-Microphone */

.no-mic::after {
  content: 'Mute Mic';
}

.no-mic::before {
  content: '\f539';
}


/* Play */

.play::after {
  content: 'Play';
}

.play::before {
  content: '\f04b';
}
```

```html
<link href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container">
  <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block icon music" role="button"></a>

  <a class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block icon no-mic" role="button"></a>

  <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block icon play" role="button"></a>
</div>

<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: But I am using Font Awesome v5, so I don't see why I should not use `fas`

Comment: Your fiddle is using 4.7

Comment: I tried with 5.0.13 and it seems that the only property that actually affects FA is `line-height`

Comment: Indeed you are correct. Updated answer as befits v5.0.13. FA4 to FA5 are completely different so disregard former answer.