# Bootstrap icon misalignment

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align my words with icon. I tried the methods from this site: [Vertical alignment of text and icon in button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478710/vertical-alignment-of-text-and-icon-in-button)

[current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7hq5.png)

My code:

```
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-8">
        <h3><%= link_to item.title, item , id: "font-colour" %></h3>    
        <p><%=  if item.description.length > 70
                    item.description[0..70].gsub(/\s\w+\s*$/, '...')
                else 
                    item.description
                end
        %></p>  

    </div>     

    <%= link_to complete_item_path(item), id: "font-colour", method: :patch do %>
        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-2x align-center"></i>
    <% end %>

    <div class = "col-md-1">
        <%= link_to item_path(item), id: "font-colour", method: :delete do %>
            <i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x align-center"></i>
        <%end%>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `display: flex;align-items: center;` to `row` could be helpful:

```html
<div class = "row" style="display: flex;align-items: center;">
    <div class = "col-md-8">
        <h3><%= link_to item.title, item , id: "font-colour" %></h3>    
        <p><%=  if item.description.length > 70
                    item.description[0..70].gsub(/\s\w+\s*$/, '...')
                else 
                    item.description
                end
        %></p>  

    </div>     

    <%= link_to complete_item_path(item), id: "font-colour", method: :patch do %>
        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-2x align-center"></i>
    <% end %>

    <div class = "col-md-1">
        <%= link_to item_path(item), id: "font-colour", method: :delete do %>
            <i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x align-center"></i>
        <%end%>
    </div> 
</div>
```