# Button text not properly centered in laravel and bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a button in my laravel application

```
<a href="{{ url('/product') }}" class="btn btn-default px-5 mt-3 rounded subscribe" role="button">{{ __('More info') }}</a>
```

So I need the button text to be centered in the button. But currently the text is not properly centered to the button

[image]

Currently the button look like this. The text is not well centered.

In my css I have following code for the class, subscribe

```
.subscribe {
            background-color: #5ABDBA;
            color: #fff;
            border-radius: 40px!important;
            height: 43px;
            text-transform: capitalize!important;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
```

And I'm using bootstrap 4 .

Comment: Do you have a link to the live webpage?

Comment: nope, locally  developing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertical alignment of text and icon in button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478710/vertical-alignment-of-text-and-icon-in-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why force the button  height ?

And always favor framework existing classes

```
.subscribe { background-color: #5abdba; }

<a href="/" class="btn btn-default px-5 mt-3 rounded-pill text-white text-capitalize subscribe"  role="button">{{ __('More info') }}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep height in css then in class of a tag set `d-flex` and `align-items-center`