# how can I center text in button?

Tags: css

[image]

I need to center `&times;` in my button.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style>
        .modal-default-close {
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 130px;
            right: 48%;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            border-radius: 23px;
            background-color: #898A8F;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 40px;
            opacity: 1;
            z-index: 10;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>



    <button type="button" class="btn modal-default-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>


   
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertical alignment of text and icon in button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478710/vertical-alignment-of-text-and-icon-in-button)

Comment: can you apply your suggestion in snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a negative `margin-top` to it.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style>
        .modal-default-close {
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 130px;
            right: 48%;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            border-radius: 23px;
            background-color: #898A8F;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 40px;
            opacity: 1;
            z-index: 10;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .btn>span{ margin-top:-0.21em}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <button type="button" class="btn modal-default-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</body>

</html>
```