# Center icon in a div - horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues centering icons (both vertically and horizontally) in a parent div.  I have many parent `divs` on my page that are different sizes, so I want to be able to proportionally place icons in the center of each parent div. Here's a JSFiddle of the problem:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kVHbV/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="img_container">
  <i class="icon-play-circle"></i>
</div>
<br>
<div class="img_container2">
  <i class="icon-play-circle"></i>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.img_container{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    background:red;
}

.img_container2{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    position:relative;
    background:blue;
}

.icon-play-circle{
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    left:45%;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Since they are already `inline-block` child elements, you can set `text-align:center` on the parent without having to set a `width` or `margin:0px auto` on the child. Meaning it will work for dynamically generated content with varying `widths`.

```
.img_container, .img_container2 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

This will center the child within both `div` containers.

**UPDATE:**

For vertical centering, you can use the `calc()` function assuming the height of the icon is known.

```
.img_container > i, .img_container2 > i {
    position:relative;
    top: calc(50% - 10px); /* 50% - 3/4 of icon height */
}
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aHUtM/6/) - it works.

For what it's worth - you can also use `vertical-align:middle` assuming `display:table-cell` is set on the parent.

Comment: doesn't this only center the child horizontally (and not vertically?)

Comment: @scientiffic Yea, this will only center horizontally.. You didn't say that you wanted it vertically, do you what it that way also?

Comment: yes, sorry that I didn't clarify.  the main issue is having it center vertically.

Comment: @scientiffic Alright, give me a few mins. I'll update my answer.

Comment: vertical-align: middle but also line-height: 100px?

Comment: @scientiffic Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/aHUtM/1/

Comment: Those don't look centered; they look like the image is beginning at at the center line.

If it's not important that the icon be an image and the DIV it's in has a fixed size, you could set the background-image to be the picture with background-repeat: no-repeat and background-position: center center.

Comment: @Otis This is what i'm getting: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ulmD8.png

Comment: When I load your image (or a screen-shot of the jsfiddle) into Paint.NET, I'm counting 100px above the circle and 88px below the circle which isn't centered; the circle takes up the other 12px.

Try: http://jsfiddle.net/aHUtM/2/

Comment: @JoshC your vertical centering solution doesn't work in this context. He specifically said there will be many different div heights to account for (which means your code is an approximation of vertical centering at best) and furthermore you are assuming that each div has fixed and known height which is not a safe assumption.

Comment: thanks again for your help.  it's almost working, but when I adjust the size of the divs, it isn't centered vertically: http://jsfiddle.net/aHUtM/4/

Comment: @Ennui If you read through the comments, you will notice that he didn't originally state he wanted it done both vertically and horizontally. I posted a solution for horizontal centering. He later updated the question to include both. At the time I posted this solution it worked in the context assuming that the content was of differing widths and not of varying heights.

Comment: @scientiffic I updated it to include calc() http://jsfiddle.net/aHUtM/6/ assuming the height of the icon is known.

Comment: thanks, Josh, I didn't know about calc!  it works great.  can you add it as an answer, and I'll mark it was the correct one?

Comment: @scientiffic I updated it

Comment: @scientiffic or you can mark my solution which is less verbose and works in all situations without knowing height or width of the parent container OR the element being centered ;)

Comment: @JoshC I left the icon wrapped because that's how his markup was to begin with!

Comment: I guess this is the "bestest" solution. :D

Answer (score 22):

Here is a way to center content both vertically and horizontally in any situation, which is useful when you do not know the width or height or both:

**CSS**

```
#container {
    display: table;
    width: 300px; /* not required, just for example */
    height: 400px; /* not required, just for example */
}

#update {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <a id="update" href="#">
        <i class="icon-refresh"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5avEf/)

Note that the width and height values are just for demonstration here, you can change them to anything you want (or remove them entirely) and it will still work because the vertical centering here is a product of the way the `table-cell` display property works.

Answer (score 8):

Horizontal centering is as easy as:

```
text-align: center
```

Vertical centering when the container is a known height:

```
height: 100px;
line-height: 100px;
vertical-align: middle
```

Vertical centering when the container isn't a known height AND you can set the image in the background:

```
background: url(someimage) no-repeat center center;
```