# need help to center Font Awesome icon in my Bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, icons, center

This is my code i need to center the icon with inline css:

```
<div class="small-4 medium-4 large-4 columns">
    <i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-lg"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: text-align center parent div

Answer (score 7):

If you are using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) you should only add `text-center` class

```
<div class="small-4 medium-4 large-4 columns text-center">
    <i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-lg"></i>
</div>
```

Else you can add this inline css to your parent `div`

```
text-align: center
```

So it will be :

```
<div style="text-align: center" class="small-4 medium-4 large-4 columns">
    <i  class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-lg"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Thany you very much ^^

Comment: @Tate If my answer was useful, you can press ✔

Comment: It looks like font awesome icons are treated as text. However, this only solves the horizontally alignment. For the vertical alignment which sometimes doesn't work if the line height is not same as the parent box height, these two  are helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309928/how-to-center-text-vertically-with-a-large-font-awesome-icon, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124255/center-icon-in-a-div-horizontally-and-vertically

Answer (score 1):

Give the width to the container div of  icon and give `text-align:center` to that div

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
   <div style="width:100%;text-align:center" class="small-4 medium-4 large-4 columns">
          <i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-lg"></i>
        </div><body>
  
  </body>
  </html>
```

You can also add `text-center` class to container div

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style,

```
 .columns {
  text-align: center;
   }
```