# Down arrow on drop down button on nav bar

Tags: html, css

On my nav bar I have drop-down menu and I want to insert down arrow in this button, but how I should do this ? I can use `&#9660` character, but what if I want to have diferrent arrow ?  This is my code to insert `img` in `a` https://jsfiddle.net/adriansikora344/cgfd5cxk/ I'm using `position absolute` for `img` becouse when I change text font size I have constant position, but `top: 50% - 16px` is correctly ? Meybe I should use this tag for span ?

Comment: You did insert a down arrow in your fiddle, right? What is it exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: How i could insert image on my nav bar and text for description, something like this https://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: See if this flexbox answer helps at all http://stackoverflow.com/a/39161435/3377049

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `background-image`

```css
body {
  padding: 20px 20px;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url('https://img.clipartfest.com/c37b8d1f47f75c7cf1f8f37ede371252_red-down-arrow-clip-art-at-down-arrow-clipart_600-600.png') calc(100% - 10px) center no-repeat / 16px 16px;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<a>text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can still use the img tag with position absolute but change the top be `top: 50%;` and add `transform: translateY(-50%);` Example: https://jsfiddle.net/cgfd5cxk/3/

You can read more about centering elements here: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Is this the layout you want?

It uses an icon instead of an image but you can just replace the `i` tag with your `img` tag and adjust the css.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
.link {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.link span {
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.link i {

}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="link" href="https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/cgfd5cxk/5/">
  <span>text</span>
  <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down"></i>
</a>
```

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/cgfd5cxk/5/

**Font Awesome**

Also, [here's the list](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) of current Font Awesome icons and this is the link to load the font in your html..

`https//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css`