# Dynamic positioning of a React JSX button

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I am working with React and I need put this button like that:

[image]

but I have a big problem because I am forbidden to use margin or other form of positional where I have values with px, or rem, basicaly static positional. Now, I have this code

```
<div style={{ float: 'right' }}>
      <ActionButton style={{
        display : 'flex', 
        flex : '1',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems : 'center', 
        justifyContent : 'center',
        height: '40px',
        width: '151px',

      }} name={<div style = {{
        display : 'flex',
        flex : '2',
      backgroundColor : 'red', 
      float : 'right'
    }}>FILTRAR</div>} 
      icon={<div style = {{
        display : 'flex',
        flex : '2',
      backgroundColor : 'blue',
      width: '24px',
      height: '24px',
      float : 'left'}}><FilterIcon/></div>}>
      </ActionButton>
    </div>
```

And now my button is like that

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center text vertically with a large font-awesome icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309928/how-to-center-text-vertically-with-a-large-font-awesome-icon)

Comment: It would be better if you setup repl.it or another react-native sandbox so we can test it live. Otherwise, it is more like a guess :) Check out my answer

Comment: What is the code of the second screenshot? Now their heights look equal, seems like it's a bit closer to solution

Comment: I don´t know do this...
I put the code in the question and thanks for help me

Comment: Still, it's better to upload all of the code, not it's screenshots :) Anyway, I updated my second sandbox with `styled-components`, try to play with it by adding your real code to this sandbox step by step, hope you'll get your issue fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parent's styles should already align children (name and icon) by the center, not by the top. And yes, no positioning styles are required, unless there are hardcoded heigh/margin values in children itself.

Desired behavior can be broken because of the implementation of `ActionButton`.

Anyway, my suggestions to tackle this issue:

1. use `flex-direction: 'row-reverse'` instead of `float`s;
2. remove `display: 'flex'` from child elements.

Here is a simplified and working example for web https://codesandbox.io/s/62nynm1wzk, hope it can help you to get started.

**Update:** here is an example using `button` instead of `div` as container, since it is closer to original markup: https://codesandbox.io/s/y7q1vlwkwj

Comment: I did like you said and I understood your code but didn´t work

Comment: <div style={{ float: 'right' }}>
         
          <ActionButton style={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          height: '40px',
          width: '151px',
        }} icon={<div style = {{height : '24px', width: '24px'}}><FilterIcon/></div> }
        name={<div>Filtros</div>} ></ActionButton>
          
        </div>

Comment: Result is still the same as in your question? If so, try to replace components one by one: replace parent with plain div and render icon and text as children

Comment: I put the result in the question

Comment: But in the component or in actionbutton?

Comment: First, try to replace ActionButton with plain div or button. If not worked out, return ActionButton and try replacing one of it's children: icon or text, then second children. One of these components break the layout. Here is updated button example https://codesandbox.io/s/y7q1vlwkwj

Comment: I don´t know do this... I put the code in the question and thanks for help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin in % (ie: 50%) and then use transforms, in percent (ie: transform: translateX(-50%), to adjust position. If you can provide a static stylable html I can produce an example for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the **flex** and **display** style property in name and icon props like below and check it. Because **flex:2** will change the width of child element with equal spacing.

```
<div style={{ float: 'right' }}>
      <ActionButton style={{
        display : 'flex', 
        flex : '1',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems : 'center', 
        justifyContent : 'center',
        height: '40px',
        width: '151px',

      }} name={<div style = {{
      backgroundColor : 'red', 
      float : 'right'
    }}>FILTRAR</div>} 
      icon={<div style = {{
      backgroundColor : 'blue',
      width: '24px',
      height: '24px',
      float : 'left'}}><FilterIcon/></div>}>
      </ActionButton>
    </div>
```